# VS2015 + Cordova + HockeyApp +Windows Mobile

Tags: visual-studio-cordova, hockeyapp

Anyone have experience/documentation integrating the HockeyApp SDK into a VS2015 Community Windows 10 Mobile Cordova app and adding the version to the HockeyApp dashboard?

When I use HockeyApp on my Windows device, I see the following error when I try to install 
`This App cannot be installed over the air.`

I packaged the app using `Project > Store > Create App Packages` and uploaded the .aapx from the `AppPackages`.  I select `no` when the wizard asks if `Do you want to build packages to upload to the Windows Phone 
Store?`
[image]

Any thoughts?

In addition, When I upload the release apk, or aapx I get the following on the HockeyApp dashboard. 
`No statistics found. Please integrate HockeySDK to collect analytics, crash reports, and feedback:`
[image]

Note: I am using the cordova-hockeyapp-plugin for Android and IOS.
https://github.com/wnyc/cordova-plugin-hockeyapp

Comment: One note on part of your question: The HockeyApp SDK plugin does not yet support Windows.

Comment: @ChuckLantz HockeyApp appears to be requesting a .aetx files.  However, when I try to generate one using `AetGenerator.exe` and  `CordovaApp_TemporaryKey.pfx` or `CordovaApp.pfx` I get the following error.   `invalid certificate or password`.  Note: The password is blank for the .pfk files.  Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`This App cannot be installed over the air.` error appears because an `.aetx` is required.  An `.aetx` is generated using a purchased `Enterprise Mobile Code Signing Certificate from Symantec Corp` and `AetGenerator.exe`

However, if you want to use the native HockeyApp for sideloading on the device, you'll still get `This App cannot be installed over the air.`

Note: An `.aetx` is not necessary for sideloading Windows 10 mobile apps.  Unfortunately, the native HockeyApp does not have the ability to download and install the app for sideloading.  Instead, the app should be download and sideloaded to the device via the web ui.

Solution:

- Purchase `Symantec Certificate` to create `.aetx`

or

- Sideload apps using the HockeyApp web ui.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

Right click your project and select store, then click `Create App Packages`. Select `no` as you mentioned, click `next`, you can set `Version` and output type in the page. Check `ARM` and click create button. You may upload `.appx` file to Hockeyapp. Hockeyapp will create a new project in the dashboard.

Did you sign your app for company app distribution as described [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj206943(v=vs.105).aspx)?

If yes, please upload your .aetx token to the app page, then the download page should offer both files and the installation should work.

Did you set the right App ID? Does the version exist on HockeyApp? If you set right, the crash report will appear.

Comment: John,  thanks for the help. Creating the .aetx token seems to be the problem? I upload the `.appx` but was unsuccessful in creating a .aetx token.  When I follow the instructions [https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj735576(v=vs.105).aspx](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj735576(v=vs.105).aspx) I get `'C:\Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file `.

Comment: However, if I use `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows Phone\v8.0\Tools\AETGenerator\AetGenerator.exe PFXFile Password`  I get `Invalid certificate or password`.  Is an .aetx file required when developing for Windows 10 phone?

Comment: According to the official document:[link](http://support.hockeyapp.net/kb/app-management-2/how-to-create-a-new-app#windows-amp-windows-phone), .aetx is needed. Drag & drop the .aetx file to the app page. Or click on the little triangle next to Add Version and select Upload Company Profile.

Comment: Unfortunately, I am having no luck generating a .aetx from the automatically created `CordovaApp.pfx` file.  I still get the same `Invalid certificate or password`.  The link below has the .pfx, and I believe the password is blank [https://github.com/dbiele/TypeScript-Cordova-SystemJS-Angular2-beta/tree/master/res/native/windows](https://github.com/dbiele/TypeScript-Cordova-SystemJS-Angular2-beta/tree/master/res/native/windows)  
Any thoughts?

Comment: You were correct about signing the app.  Unfortunately, the documentation wasn't clear to me.   It appears as though the Enterprise Mobile Code Signing Certificate from Symantec Corp is required to make an .aetx. The .aetx enables apps be be installed over the air installation on the Windows Phone HockeyApp